# Solve $a=\frac{b+c}{1+b^2c^2},b=\frac{a+c}{1+a^2c^2}, c=\frac{a+b}{1+a^2b^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, systems-of-equations

Let $a,b,c> 0$ such that $$a=\frac{b+c}{1+b^2c^2},b=\frac{a+c}{1+a^2c^2}, c=\frac{a+b}{1+a^2b^2}$$

Prove that the only solution to this system of equations is $$a=b=c=1$$

I am getting this answer using numerical simulations, but haven't been able to prove this algebraically.

EDIT: I am specifically looking for an argument that utilizes inequalities, and is an equality only for $a=b=c=1$.

Comment: $a=b=c=0$ is another solution (was before edit)

Comment: @anchova- Thanks, I have now altered the condition to say $a,b,c>0$. The equations from which the above question is derived hold only for non-zero $a,b,c$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $s = a+b+c$ and $p = abc$. Then, we have $$\begin{align}a = \dfrac{b+c}{1+b^2c^2} &= \dfrac{s-a}{1+\tfrac{p^2}{a^2}} \\ a\left(1+\dfrac{p^2}{a^2}\right) &= s-a \\ a^2+p^2 &= sa-a^2 \\ 2a^2-sa+p^2 &= 0 \\ a &= \dfrac{s + \epsilon_a\sqrt{s^2-8p^2}}{4},\end{align}$$ where $\epsilon_a = +1$ or $\epsilon_a = -1$, and similarly for $b$ and $c$. Hence, $$\begin{align}s = a+b+c &= \dfrac{3s + (\epsilon_a+\epsilon_b+\epsilon_c)\sqrt{s^2-8p^2}}{4} \\ s &= (\epsilon_a+\epsilon_b+\epsilon_c)\sqrt{s^2-8p^2}\end{align}$$

Since $a,b,c, > 0$, we have $s > 0$, and so we can only have $\epsilon_a+\epsilon_b+\epsilon_c = 1$ or $3$.

If $\epsilon_a+\epsilon_b+\epsilon_c = 1$, then we get $s = \sqrt{s^2-8p^2}$, which yields $p = 0$, which isn't possible since $a,b,c > 0$.

If $\epsilon_a+\epsilon_b+\epsilon_c = 3$, then we have $\epsilon_a = \epsilon_b = \epsilon_c = +1$, i.e. $a = b = c$. Substituting yields $a = \dfrac{b+c}{1+b^2c^2} = \dfrac{2a}{1+a^4}$, and solving yields $a = b = c = 1$ (since $a,b,c > 0$).

Therefore, $a = b = c = 1$ is the only positive solution.

Comment: This is amazing. How did you get the idea for the $\epsilon_i$ argument? Is this something that you've seen before?

Comment: Setting $s = a+b+c$ and $p = abc$ "symmetrizes" the problem in the sense that all three variables are solutions to the same equation and reduces things from dealing with three variables to dealing with two. I've definitely used something like it a few times before, but it's been a few years.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution by substitution :

Substitute $x=bc$, $y=ca$, $z=ab$. Then we get the following.

$$\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{x}+x$$

$$\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{y}+y$$

$$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{z}+z$$

This implies the following.

$$\frac{2}{x}+x=\frac{2}{y}+y = \frac{2}{z}+z $$

By the property of second-order polynomial equation, at least two of $x,y,z$ should be same. WLOG $x=y$, and we get $xz=yz=1$.

Finally, we get $x=\frac{1}{x}$, and $x=y=z=1$. This implies $a=b=c=1$. It is easy to check that this is indeed a unique solution.

Answer (score 3):

From the system of equations, we have
\begin{align*}
 a^2 + a^2b^2c^2 &= a(b + c), \tag{1}\\
 b^2 + a^2b^2c^2 &= b(c + a), \tag{2}\\
 c^2 + a^2b^2c^2 &= c(a + b). \tag{3}
\end{align*}

$(1) - (2)$ yields
$$(a - b)(a + b - c) = 0. \tag{4}$$

$(2) - (3)$ yields
$$(b - c)(b + c - a) = 0. \tag{5}$$

We claim that $a = b$. Indeed,
if $a + b - c = 0$, we have $c = a + b$,
which, when plugged into (5), gives
$-2ab = 0$ which is impossible.

From $a = b$ and (5), we have $(b-c)c = 0$
which results in $b = c$.

From (1) and $a = b = c$, we have $a^6 = a^2$ which results in $a = 1$.

We are done.